# Multiple feignclients using boilerplate interfaces from single spring service

Tags: java, spring, consul, feign, openfeign

im trying to setup a proxy to multiple spring controllers using feignclients.

A very simple explanation of the architecture is that im creating spring microservices and using consul for service discovery and a key-value store (mainly used for registering several instances of the same service, later loadbalanced).

The spring service has several public api (e.g. UserApi & UserAuthApi in my case):

```
public interface UserAuthApi {
    
    @Deprecated
    @GetMapping("/auth/login")
    UserAuthDto getAuthUserByEmail(@RequestParam("email") String email);
...
```

In a different service I would like to setup boilerplate Feignclients using these api's. I have one running and working for UserAuthApi:

```
@FeignClient(name = "mcs-user", path = "/user")
public interface UserAuthApiProxy extends UserAuthApi {
}
```

However I am unable to use this principle when trying to create a proxy for the other api:

```
@FeignClient(name = "mcs-user", path = "/user")
public interface UserApiProxy extends UserApi {
}
```

Instead as a temp. workaround im able remove the 'extends UserApi' and copy the method definition within my proxy. I couldnt find any information or examples of using multiple boilerplate apis from one service like i am trying to make. I have tried setting '-parameters' when researching solutions to the error shown, but it didnt affect anything.

As well I tried creating a @RequestMapping(...) for these interfaces to differentiate their paths, and within feignclient interface append the value, but didnt change at all.
Besides that, I do have 'spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true' in my application properties as well.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService': Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userApi': Error creating bean with name 'sk.fmfi.listng.rest.proxy.user.UserApiProxy': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:693) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:482) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at sk.fmfi.listng.rest.RestApplication.main(RestApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userApi': Error creating bean with name 'sk.fmfi.listng.rest.proxy.user.UserApiProxy': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:693) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:482) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:710) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sk.fmfi.listng.rest.proxy.user.UserApiProxy': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:154) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:90) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1823) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1273) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:259) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1640) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:710) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RequestParam.value() was empty on parameter 1
    at feign.Util.checkState(Util.java:136) ~[feign-core-12.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.annotation.RequestParamParameterProcessor.processArgument(RequestParamParameterProcessor.java:63) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringMvcContract.processAnnotationsOnParameter(SpringMvcContract.java:298) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(Contract.java:126) ~[feign-core-12.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringMvcContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(SpringMvcContract.java:197) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(Contract.java:65) ~[feign-core-12.1.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$ParseHandlersByName.apply(ReflectiveFeign.java:142) ~[feign-core-12.1.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign.newInstance(ReflectiveFeign.java:58) ~[feign-core-12.1.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign.newInstance(ReflectiveFeign.java:50) ~[feign-core-12.1.jar:na]
    at feign.Feign$Builder.target(Feign.java:197) ~[feign-core-12.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.DefaultTargeter.target(DefaultTargeter.java:30) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.loadBalance(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:398) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getTarget(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:446) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getObject(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:148) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Is there a way to achieve these boilerplate apis from one service without having to copy the method definition from the target api to my feignclient interface (obviously this means a problem with having to maintain code at two places at the same time)?

Thank you in advance for any comments and help :)